# System wide libxml2 not working, compilation from sources failes in configure

Tags: c++, linux, libxml2, autotools, powerpc

## System Wide libxml2

I want to compile the Chroma suite of physics simulations on the JUQUEEN supercomputer which is an IBM BlueGene/Q installation. The frontends run on RedHat Linux 6. Architecture is PowerPC 7 on both frontend and compute nodes. They CPUs used differ though, the frontend has IBM Power 740, the compute nodes are IBM Power A2 chips. Using compilers like `mpigcc` and `mpig++` automatically cross compile for the compute nodes.

Modern versions of programs can be loaded into the path using `module`. There are dependencies on two other libraries that have to be compiled. I am done with `qmp` for now. `qdpxx` also depends on `libxml2` and this is where I am stuck:

```
chroma --- qdpxx --- qmp
                 \-- libxml2
```

On my Fedora 24 workstation, I can compile `qdpxx` just fine using the system wide installation of `libxml2`. I have just installed the RPM packages `libxml2` and `libxml2-devel` and did not have to specify any `-with-libxml2=DIR` arguments to `qdpxx/configure`.

On the supercomputer frontend, I get this:

```
+ ./configure --prefix=/homec/hbn28/hbn28e/local/ --host=powerpc64-bgq-linux --build=powerpc64-unknown-linux-gnu --enable-bgq-thread-binding --enable-openmp --enable-parallel-arch=parscalar --enable-precision=double --enable-parallel-io --enable-qdp-alignment=128 --with-qmp=/homec/hbn28/hbn28e/local/ 'CFLAGS=-O2 -finline-limit=50000 -I/usr/local/bg_soft/mpich3/include -Wall -Wpedantic -fdiagnostics-color=auto --std=c99 -fopenmp --std=gnu99' 'CXXFLAGS=-O2 -finline-limit=50000 -I/usr/local/bg_soft/mpich3/include -Wall -Wpedantic -fdiagnostics-color=auto --std=c++11 -fopenmp' LDFLAGS= LIBS= CC=/bgsys/local/gcc/4.9.3/bin/mpigcc CXX=/bgsys/local/gcc/4.9.3/bin/mpig++
checking for C++ compiler default output file name... a.out
checking whether the C++ compiler works... yes
checking whether we are cross compiling... yes
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
checking whether /bgsys/local/gcc/4.9.3/bin/mpig++ accepts -g... yes
checking for powerpc64-bgq-linux-ranlib... no
checking for ranlib... ranlib
configure: WARNING: using cross tools not prefixed with host triplet
checking for powerpc64-bgq-linux-ar... no
checking for ar... ar
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for powerpc64-bgq-linux-strip... no
checking for strip... strip
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking for style of include used by make... GNU
checking dependency style of /bgsys/local/gcc/4.9.3/bin/mpig++... gcc3
configure: Configuring QDP++ for Nd = 4
configure: Configuring QDP++ for Nc = 3
configure: Configuring QDP++ for Ns = 4
configure: Configuring QDP++ Alignment size=16
configure: Fallback to generic C routines if needed: yes
configure: Enabling BGQ Thread Binding
configure: Configuring for double precision  
configure: Configuring QDP++ with cb2 layout
configure:  Parscalar build! Checking for QMP 
checking for qmp-config... /homec/hbn28/hbn28e/local//bin/qmp-config
configure: Found QMP configuration program /homec/hbn28/hbn28e/local//bin/qmp-config
configure: QMP compile flags: -I/homec/hbn28/hbn28e/local/include
configure: QMP linking flags: -L/homec/hbn28/hbn28e/local/lib
configure: QMP libraries flags: -lqmp
checking if we can compile/link of a simple QMP C++ program... yes
Value of with_libxml2 is XX
checking for xml2-config... /usr/bin/xml2-config
configure: Found libxml2 configuration program 
configure: libxml2 compile flags: -I/usr/include/libxml2
configure: libxml2 libraries flags: -lxml2 -lz -lm
checking if we can compile/link a simple libxml2 program... no
configure: error: Cannot compile/link a program with libxml2.
    Use --with-libxml2=<dir> to select a working version.
```

In `qdpxx/config.log`, the relevant section is this here:

```
configure:4321: checking for xml2-config
configure:4339: found /usr/bin/xml2-config
configure:4351: result: /usr/bin/xml2-config
configure:4370: Found libxml2 configuration program 
configure:4374: libxml2 compile flags: -I/usr/include/libxml2
configure:4378: libxml2 libraries flags: -lxml2 -lz -lm
configure:4386: checking if we can compile/link a simple libxml2 program
configure:4434: /bgsys/local/gcc/4.9.3/bin/mpig++ -o conftest -O2 -finline-limit=50000 -I/usr/local/bg_soft/mpich3/include -Wall -Wpedantic -fdiagnostics-color=auto --std=c++11 -fopenmp -I/usr/include/libxml2    conftest.cpp  -lxml2 -lz -lm >&5
conftest.cpp: In function 'int main()':
conftest.cpp:30:16: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]
  char *docname="foo";
                ^
conftest.cpp:28:13: warning: unused variable 'argc' [-Wunused-variable]
         int argc ; char **argv ;
             ^
conftest.cpp:28:27: warning: unused variable 'argv' [-Wunused-variable]
         int argc ; char **argv ;
                           ^
conftest.cpp:29:19: warning: variable 'doc' set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
         xmlDocPtr doc;
                   ^
/usr/local/bg_soft/gcc/4.9.3/bin/../lib/gcc/powerpc64-bgq-linux/4.9.3/../../../../powerpc64-bgq-linux/bin/ld: cannot find -lxml2
/usr/local/bg_soft/gcc/4.9.3/bin/../lib/gcc/powerpc64-bgq-linux/4.9.3/../../../../powerpc64-bgq-linux/bin/ld: cannot find -lz
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
configure:4441: $? = 1
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h.  */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME "qdp++"
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME "qdp--"
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION "1.44.0"
| #define PACKAGE_STRING "qdp++ 1.44.0"
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT "edwards@jlab.org"
| #define PACKAGE "qdp--"
| #define VERSION "1.44.0"
| #define QDP_ND 4
| #define QDP_NC 3
| #define QDP_NS 4
| #define QDP_AC_ALIGNMENT_SIZE 16
| #define QDP_USE_GENERIC_OPTS 1
| #define QDP_USE_BLUEGENEL 1
| #define BASE_PRECISION 64
| #define QDP_USE_CB2_LAYOUT 1
| #define ARCH_PARSCALAR 1
| #define QDP_USE_LIBXML2 1
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| 
|         #include <libxml/xmlmemory.h>
|       #include <libxml/parser.h>
| 
| int
| main ()
| {
| 
|         int argc ; char **argv ;
|         xmlDocPtr doc;
|       char *docname="foo";
|       doc = xmlParseFile(docname);
|          ;
|          ;
| 
|   ;
|   return 0;
| }
configure:4483: result: no
configure:4486: error: Cannot compile/link a program with libxml2.
    Use --with-libxml2=<dir> to select a working version.
```

The `cannot find -lxml2` sounds like there is no `/usr/lib/libxml2.so`. And indeed, there is none there. Running `locate libxml` gives the following interesting lines:

```
/usr/include/libxml2/libxml/xpath.h
...
/usr/include/libxml2/libxml/xpointer.h
/usr/lib/libxml2.so.2
/usr/lib/libxml2.so.2.7.6
/usr/lib64/libxml2.so
/usr/lib64/libxml2.so.2
/usr/lib64/libxml2.so.2.7.6
```

Apparently the 32-bit version has a strange so-name and only the 64-bit version has a regular so-name. Trying to add `-L/usr/lib64` turned out to break other things:

```
+ ./configure --prefix=/homec/hbn28/hbn28e/local/ --host=powerpc64-bgq-linux --build=powerpc64-unknown-linux-gnu --enable-bgq-thread-binding --enable-openmp --enable-parallel-arch=parscalar --enable-precision=double --enable-parallel-io --enable-qdp-alignment=128 --with-qmp=/homec/hbn28/hbn28e/local/ 'CFLAGS=-O2 -finline-limit=50000 -I/usr/local/bg_soft/mpich3/include -Wall -Wpedantic -fdiagnostics-color=auto --std=c99 -fopenmp --std=gnu99' 'CXXFLAGS=-O2 -finline-limit=50000 -I/usr/local/bg_soft/mpich3/include -Wall -Wpedantic -fdiagnostics-color=auto --std=c++11 -fopenmp' LDFLAGS=-L/usr/lib64/ LIBS= CC=/bgsys/local/gcc/4.9.3/bin/mpigcc CXX=/bgsys/local/gcc/4.9.3/bin/mpig++
checking for C++ compiler default output file name... 
configure: error: in `/homec/hbn28/hbn28e/qdpxx':
configure: error: C++ compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details.
```

In the log file, it says the following:

```
configure:2159: /bgsys/local/gcc/4.9.3/bin/mpig++ -O2 -finline-limit=50000 -I/usr/local/bg_soft/mpich3/include -Wall -Wpedantic -fdiagnostics-color=auto --std=c++11 -fopenmp  -L/usr/lib64/ conftest.cpp  >&5
/usr/local/bg_soft/gcc/4.9.3/bin/../lib/gcc/powerpc64-bgq-linux/4.9.3/../../../../powerpc64-bgq-linux/lib/crt1.o: In function `_start_no_magic':
(.text+0x58): undefined reference to `__libc_no_magic_start_main'
/bgsys/local/gcc/4.9.3/powerpc64-bgq-linux/lib/libdl.so.2: undefined reference to `_dl_addr_range@GLIBC_PRIVATE'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
configure:2163: $? = 1
configure:2201: result: 
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h.  */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME "qdp++"
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME "qdp--"
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION "1.44.0"
| #define PACKAGE_STRING "qdp++ 1.44.0"
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT "edwards@jlab.org"
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| 
| int
| main ()
| {
| 
|   ;
|   return 0;
| }
configure:2207: error: in `/homec/hbn28/hbn28e/qdpxx':
configure:2210: error: C++ compiler cannot create executables
```

It seems that I have just junked all other paths where libraries can reside such that nothing builds any more.

Trying to create a symlink from `/usr/lib/libxml2.so.2` to `$HOME/libxml2.so` and addling `-L$HOME` has not worked either.

## Trying to Compile libxml2 from Git

At this point I stopped pursuing the system wide installation and tried to install `libxml2` from the Git repository. So I have cloned the repository and typed `./autogen.sh`. This failed saying:

```
Checking zlib
./configure: line 12546: syntax error near unexpected token `Z,zlib,'
./configure: line 12546: `    PKG_CHECK_MODULES(Z,zlib,'
```

The autotools there claim to be version 2.69. This is the same version installed on the university cluster (where it also fails). On my Fedora 24 workstation that same version is installed but `./autogen.sh` just runs through and creates a `Makefile`.

---

I am a bit lost now. Is there a bug in the build script of `libxml2` if it fails on the `ppc64` RedHat and also on the `amd64` Debian university cluster but not my `x86_64` Fedora laptop?

How could I get the `configure` script of `qdpxx` to use the system wide installation of `libxml2`? It does already extract the proper flags using `xml2-config`:

```
configure: libxml2 compile flags: -I/usr/include/libxml2
configure: libxml2 libraries flags: -lxml2 -lz -lm
```

What can I do to get my program compiled further?

Comment: Try setting target to `ppc64` or `powerpc64`. This should automatically build your code to 64-bit binary.

Comment: non-versioned shared libraries are usually provided by `*-devel` packages. These are just links to the versioned library. This means that only `libxml2-devel.*64` is installed. The 32 bit version isn't installed.

Comment: To solve the `PKG_CHECK_MODULES` error, simply install `pkg-config`. You can also download a tarball of an official libxml2 release that comes with a prebuilt configure script. But I'd really try to get the build with the system's libxml2 working first. If @alvits suggestion doesn't work, what about creating the symlink manually?

Comment: @nwellnhof: I added that symlink `ln -fs /usr/share/aclocal/pkg.m4 .` and it solved the `PKG_PROG_PKG_CONFIG` error but not the `syntax error`. An intermediate workaround has been to remove the offending sections from the `configure` file, but that is not really a good solution because it is a generated file.

Comment: @MartinUeding I meant a symlink from `/usr/lib/libxml2.so` to `/usr/lib/libxml2.so.2.7.6` in order to make the build with the system libxml2 work.

Comment: I cannot do that, I do not have any administrative powers (direct or indirect) on that system. On the other supercomputer that I *now* work with, the `libxml2-devel` package is not even installed, there is no system wide installation anyway. With the symlink to `pkg.m4` I now have it compiled from source on both systems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running `ln -fs /usr/share/aclocal/pkg.m4 .` in the source directory made `configure` find `PKG_PROG_PKG_CONFIG`. However, there is still the syntax error around. Rerunning `autoreconf` created a `configure` file that now has no syntax errors any more.